# preg_replace but attach to string

Tags: php, regex

I have a input that has MM/DD:

```
10/16 21:41 CC
```

I need:

```
</br> 10/16 21:41 CC
```

I am trying to do:

```
$output2 = preg_replace('/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}/','<br>/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}/',$output2);
```

But I get:

```
/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/ 21:41 CC
```

I just want to put a 
 before the date. I am sure there is someone out there who has already asked this but I am pretty sure i am using bad keywords when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way:

```
$s = '10/16 21:41 CC';
$output = preg_replace('#\d{2}/\d{2}#','</br> $0', $s);

print_r($output);
```

The output:

```
</br> 10/16 21:41 CC
```

---

- `#` - regex pattern delimiter/separator
- `$0` - points to the whole matched string